# Foreign key constraint fails in MySql

Tags: mysql

I have created the following two tables using the commands below:

```
CREATE TABLE Emp (
   Empno INT(11) NOT NULL,
   Ename VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
   Job VARCHAR(50) NULL,
   Mgrno INT(11) NULL,
   Hiredate VARCHAR(50) NULL,
   Sal INT(11) NOT NULL,
   Comm INT(11) NULL,
   Deptno INT(11) NOT NULL,
   CHECK(Sal >= 1000 AND Sal <= 10000),
   PRIMARY KEY (Empno),
   FOREIGN KEY (Deptno) REFERENCES Emp(Empno)
);

CREATE TABLE Dept (
   Deptno INT(11) NOT NULL,
   Dname VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
   Location VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (Deptno)
);
```

However, when I try to enter data in the Emp table using the following command:

```
INSERT INTO Emp (Empno, Ename, Job, Mgrno, Hiredate, Sal, Comm, Deptno) VALUES (7839, 'ALAN', 'TRAINER', NULL, '17-NOV-13', 5000, NULL, 10);
```

I get an error:

```
ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`s102859495_db`.`Emp`, CONSTRAINT `Emp_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`Deptno`) REFERENCES `Emp` (`Empno`))
```

I do not know what is causing this error and how to fix it. I have already entered the corresponding entry into the Dept table:

```
INSERT INTO Dept(Deptno, Dname, Location) VALUES (10, 'CONSULTING','ADELAIDE');
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You did use the wrong syntax in your **Emp** table creation query.

You are giving reference key to **REFERENCES Emp(Empno)**. It will be **REFERENCES Dept(Deptno)**

Check right syntax below

```
 CREATE TABLE Emp (
   Empno INT(11) NOT NULL,
   Ename VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
   Job VARCHAR(50) NULL,
   Mgrno INT(11) NULL,
   Hiredate VARCHAR(50) NULL,
   Sal INT(11) NOT NULL,
   Comm INT(11) NULL,
   Deptno INT(11) NOT NULL,
   CHECK(Sal >= 1000 AND Sal <= 10000),
   PRIMARY KEY (Empno),
   FOREIGN KEY (Deptno) REFERENCES Dept(Deptno)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message is rather clear: you are trying to create a new employee that belongs to department `10` - but this department number does not exists in the departement table yet. The foreign key constraint prevents that.

You can check if the departement exists with the following query (which should return an empty resultset):

```
SELECT * FROM Dept WHERE Deptno = 10;
```

Either add the missing department in the parent table first::

```
-- create the department
INSERT INTO Dept (Deptno, Dname, Location)
VALUES (10, 'foo', 'bar');

-- Then create the employee
INSERT INTO Emp (Empno, Ename, Job, Mgrno, Hiredate, Sal, Comm, Deptno) 
VALUES (7839, 'ALAN', 'TRAINER', NULL, '17-NOV-13', 5000, NULL, 10)
```

Or: relate the employee to a department that already exists in the departement table.

Comment: I have already done that. Sorry I did not clarify that earlier. I have edited the question.

Comment: @iblue95: if you had department 10 in the department table already, then you would not be getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

FOREIGN KEY (Deptno) REFERENCES Emp(Empno) Is nonsensense presumably you meant
FOREIGN KEY (Deptno) REFERENCES dept(deptno)